# JSP read param section

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I have a problem with passing parameters from one jsp page to the other one. Code looks like this:

home page:

```
<jsp:include page="page1.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="par1" value="1"/>
    <jsp:param name="par2" value="2"/>
    <jsp:param name="par3" value="3"/>
    <jsp:param name="par4" value="4"/>
</jsp:include>
```

and reciever:

```
<c:set var="a" value="${param.par1}" />
<c:set var="b" value="${param.par2}" />
<c:set var="c" value="${param.par3}" />
<c:set var="d" value="${param.par4}" />
<label>
"${a}"<br/>
"${b}"<br/>
"${c}"<br/>
"${d}"<br/>
"${param}"
```

and the browser displays just empty string. 
What is wrong with the param attribute?

EDIT: It is liferay app.

Answer (score 0):

The values get lost when you send the values in the way mentioned because of the scope.
Read about different scopes in servlets and Jsp.

It is better you have a servlet (intermediate b/w Jsp's) before sending the values to another jsp page.
First you send the values to a servlet.In the servlet, you have a HttpServletRequest object.
Create your Param object and set the values.
Set the Param object in HttpServletRequest object using setAttribute().
Then use RequestDispatcher to go to another jsp page.
Now you should be able to see the values.

Answer (score 0):

if your receiver code is inside page1.jsp then it will work.

Comment: A reciever is an other jsp page. I read some articles about it and I think I should use liferay-ui:include, but at this time it does not display anything.